# Can phantomjs read cookies set via javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies, phantomjs

I am trying to use phantomjs to automate the process of login into facebook. The issue is that facebook uses js codes to set cookies before the login form is submitted. Clicking on the email input box the login form can trigger the facebook js codes that set the cookies, so I created a script to click on the email box before login in, yet still I get the "Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue." message. Here is my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var data = {};
var fs = require('fs');
var CookieJar = 'cookie.json';
page.customHeaders = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0'
};
if (fs.isFile(CookieJar)) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(JSON.parse(fs.read(CookieJar)), function(x) {
        phantom.addCookie(x);
    });
}
page.open('https://www.facebook.com/login.php', function(status) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        pageloaded();
        setTimeout(function() {
            afterclick();
        }, 3000);
    }, 3000);

    function pageloaded() {
        pagex = page.evaluate(function() {
            function mouseclick(element) {
                var event = document.createEvent(
                    'MouseEvents');
                event.initMouseEvent('click', true,
                    true, window, 1, 0, 0);
                element.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
            var element = document.querySelector('#email');
            mouseclick(element);
        });
    }

    function afterclick() {
        data.content = page.content;
        fs.write(CookieJar, JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies), 'w');
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

This code basically goes to the facebook login page then clicks on the email input box. The end result should be that the cookie.json file contains the cookies facebook has set, but I don't get any cookies. I have also tried using the --cookies-file command line, seems to me that phantomjs can only store cookies set by the server side? Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It is not completely clear what is it that you are trying to do. What do you imply under "automate the process of login into facebook"? Using --cookies-file command argument you can store cookies (and thus save and reuse facebook session). Why do you want to recreate cookies manually?

Comment: What you are doing wrong, is trying to “automate” something that Facebook _doesn’t want_ you to automate.

Comment: "Using --cookies-file command argument you can store cookies (and thus save and reuse facebook session)." - I tried that, the issue is it does not work. I just get the "Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue." message after the page loads. The script I posted above is not the full version, I modified it so you guys could see that phantomjs is not storing cookies set by javascript. I was just wondering whether reading cookies set by js is something phantomjs cannot do or whether the fault is on my end.

Comment: It is strange that you should get "Cookies are not enabled" message all the time. Maybe there's really an issue with storing cookies on your system. Are you able to log in to any other site with this setup?

Comment: Yes, I can log in easily to other websites, even youtube. It must be because facebook uses javascript to store cookies, that is the only difference I have noticed between facebook and the other sites I tried.

Comment: Have you found a fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your user agent

```
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0"
```